# Take info from .csv file and add it after certain pattern

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, grep, csv

I am working with this student's info:

```
name: Romeo
e_mail: letsrock@hotmail.com
Room: 0/48
street: 1/0/48

name: April
e_mail: thebestmonth@hotmail.com
Room: 0/4
street: 1/0/4

name: Julian
e_mail: julian688@gmail.com
Room: 0/2
street: 1/0/2

name: Charles
e_mail: charlesuniv@yahoo.com
Room: 0/1
street: 1/0/1

name: Chris
e_mail: todoras@hotmail.com
Room: 0/42
street: 1/0/42

name: Richard
e_mail: richiisfun@gmail.com
Room: 0/6
street: 1/0/6
```

I also have this .csv file:

```
id,name,e_mail
st0001, Romeo, letsrock@hotmail.com
st0002, Julian, julian688@gmail.com
st0003, Chris, todoras@hotmail.com
st0004, Richard, richiisfun@gmail.com
```

I would like to take the id from .csv file and add it to the .dat file, like this:

```
name: Romeo
e_mail: letsrock@hotmail.com
Room: 0/48
street: 1/0/48
id: st0001    

name: April
e_mail: thebestmonth@hotmail.com
Room: 0/4
street: 1/0/4

name: Julian
e_mail: julian688@gmail.com
Room: 0/2
street: 1/0/2
id: st0002

name: Charles
e_mail: charlesuniv@yahoo.com
Room: 0/1
street: 1/0/1

name: Chris
e_mail: todoras@hotmail.com
Room: 0/42
street: 1/0/42
id: st0003

name: Richard
e_mail: richiisfun@gmail.com
Room: 0/6
street: 1/0/6
id: st0004
```

So far I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

    FILE1=students.dat
    FILE2=table.csv

    while read line; do
        if [[ $line == name* ]]; then
            echo -e "\n$line"
            expectIp=1
        elif [[ $line == *e_mail* && $expectIp -eq 1 ]]; then
            sed 's/^\s*//' <<< $line
            unset expectIp
        elif [[ $line == Room* ]]; then
            Room=$(echo $line | grep -o 'Room[^,]*,' | sed 's/,//')
            echo $Room
            echo $line | grep -o 'street*'
            justRoom=$(echo $Room | sed 's/Room: //')
            grep -A1 \"$justRoom\" $FILE2 | grep -o 'id'
        fi
    done < $FILE1
```

The last script has lots of errors.

I have found how to get the id from the .csv file:

```
grep  "richiisfun@gmail.com" students.csv | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}'
```

How can I add it to the .dat file automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -F',\s+' -lane '
   @ARGV and $h{$F[1]}=$F[0],next;

   /^name:\s+(\S+)/ && exists $h{$a=$1} .. /^$/ || eof and do{
      /^$/ || eof and $_ .= (/^$/ ? $, : $\) . ("id: " . $h{$a} // "") . (eof ? $, : $\);
   };

   print;
' table.csv students.dat
```

## Explanation

> `Perl` options

- `-F` Field Separator is set to `,\s+`
- `-l` Output Record Separator is set to `\n`
- `-a` Autosplit mode => array `@F` contains fields `$1,$2,...,$NF`
- `-n` Print only when asked to + implicit readin of lines, a.la., `awk`

> Logic

- Order of arguments is .csv file then .dat file.
- `@ARGV and` => when input file under consideration is .csv, otw .dat
- From the .csv file data, populate the hash %h with keys as Name and value as ID.
- Now when we come to process the .dat file is the where the action is
- In `Perl`, `condition1 .. condition2` is a flip-flop operator, a.la., `,` of `sed`. But it's more versatile, in the sense, we can add more conditions to the `..` inputs. In particular, in our case, `/^name:\s+(\S+)/ && $h{$a=$1}` makes for a composite `cond1` that when the line begins with name: followed by multiple whitespace and then the student name is captured and $h{$a=$1} tests whether this student name is found with a TRUE value. (N.B.: so =>  if ID were to be a zero this will trip up!). The `flip-flop` operator stays true once this step has been taken and we keep at it till we see a empty line or we hit the `EOF`. At this particular step we stuff the current line `$_` with the id data from the hash.

Comment: Warning: Use of "eof" without parentheses is ambiguous at -e line 5.
Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at -e line 5.
Search pattern not terminated or ternary operator parsed as search pattern at -e line 5.

thats what I've got in the terminal output.

Comment: This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 44 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
it works perfectly 
As @StephenRauch said i would like to understand the code.
I will search for it.

Comment: @CesarVillegas: Added an explanatory note to the Answer.